# PHP Variable use in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have seen plenty of things on the internet about how PHP variables can be turned into JavaScript ones simply by

```php
<?php

$var = "hello";

?>

<script>

var jsvar = "<?php echo $var; ?>";

alert(jsvar);

</script>
```

However it hasn't worked for me at all.

I've removed the quotes around the PHP as I thought that was the problem.

```js
var jsvar = <?php echo $var; ?>
```

However, it still doesn't alert the variable at all.

As some of the examples of this were around 4-8 years ago so I hope it has just changed, however, I'm sure I have made a mistake somewhere and would appreciate any help.

Any examples would be great.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it work as var jsvar = "helo"; ?

Comment: You do want the quotes for a string. And this needs to be in a php file, not an external js file or a plain html file. Is it?

Comment: @Nikki9696 thanks thats fixed it, sorry I didnt realise it must be in a php file, had it in a js file

Comment: You can use PHP where-ever you want, but you would have to tell your server to also check those file types for PHP which it should then also interpret.

Answer (score 0):

putting it in a php file fixed it cheers @Nikki9696

Answer (score 0):

It should work!

Your code contains no error, your server sends this code to your browser :

```
<script>
 var jsvar = "hello";
 alert(jsvar);
</script>
```

Are you sure that Javascript is enabled in your browser ?

Comment: I think you missed the PHP part, and that OP already "answered" his own question.

Comment: @Andreas the code I posted above is the code interpreted by the web browser when running the PHP script.

In other words, it's the source code of the page sent by the server